# Weird substitution is invalid error in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have been doing lot of batch work lately from the command line using its for statements. Today i decided to bundle some of the big one line for commands that i was using to a single batch file. The main problem is that variable substitution is giving me weird error in some cases. So can somebody explain me, how this is working:

```
:: Split
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /s /b *.cue') do (
pushd .
cd %%~dpF
mkdir out
cd out
echo "%%~dpF*.flac"
popd
)
```

and this:

```
:: Split
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /s /b *.cue') do (
pushd .
cd %%~dpF
mkdir out
cd out
shntool.exe split -f "%%F" -t %t -m /-?; -o flac "%%~dpF*.flac"
popd
)
```

gives me this error:

```
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~dpF*.flac"
```

Comment: this rather comes from `shntool`.Are you sure this tool supports wildcards?

Comment: i have been using the same command in the cmd (with single %) and it was working perfectly

Comment: I've no idea what `shntool` is, but I'd suspect the `%t` parameter - whatever it is. If you want to deliver `%t` to the program, then you'd need `%%t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest

```
shntool.exe split -f "%%F" -t %t -m /-?; -o flac "%%~dpF*.flac"
```

is being interpreted as

```
shntool.exe split -f "%%F" -t %~dpF*.flac"
```

as `%t -m /-?; -o flac "%` would be seen as an environment variable.

use

```
shntool.exe split -f "%%F" -t %%t -m /-?; -o flac "%%~dpF*.flac"
```

Comment: Thank you soo much... I still don't know why i did not see it :P